# Aggregate Result returning 1 product only

Tags: aggregateresult

I am getting a sum but what happens is that it only sums up one products instead of the total number of products

```
Map<String, List<aggregateresult>> MapStringListaggregateresultSAA = new Map<String, List<aggregateresult>>();
for (aggregateresult aggregatereslt : [SELECT ogg__Invoice__r.ogg__Account__c InvoiceAccount, 
                                              ogg__Product__c Prodct, 
                                              ogg__LineDescription__c LineDescriptn, 
                                              SUM(ogg__NetValue__c) amount
                                       FROM ogg__codaInvoiceLineItem__c 
                                       WHERE Product_Code__c like 'RAM%' 
                                             and ogg__Invoice__r.ogg__Account__c in: SetAcctId 
                                             and ogg__LineDescription__c in: SetMembername 
                                             and ogg__Product__c in: SetProductid 
                                       GROUP BY ogg__Invoice__r.ogg__Account__c,
                                                ogg__Product__c,
                                                ogg__LineDescription__c]) {
    if (MapStringListaggregateresultSAA.keyset().contains(
        string.valueof(aggregatereslt.get('InvoiceAccount')) + aggregatereslt.get('LineDescriptn') + aggregatereslt.get('Prodct')
       )) {
        MapStringListaggregateresultSAA.get(
            string.valueof(aggregatereslt.get('InvoiceAccount')) + aggregatereslt.get('LineDescriptn') + aggregatereslt.get('Prodct')
        ).add(aggregatereslt);
    } else {
        MapStringListaggregateresultSAA.put(
            string.valueof(aggregatereslt.get('InvoiceAccount')) + aggregatereslt.get('LineDescriptn') + aggregatereslt.get('Prodct'),
            new List<aggregateresult>{aggregatereslt}
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Please make an effort to format your code. Incredibly long lines makes it very hard to read. Could you please include some more detail in your question as to what this is intended to do and specifics about what you get back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have used `ogg__Product__c` in the `Group By` clause that's why it is returning summation for each product.

Remove `ogg__Product__c` from Group By to get sum of products.

Refer [GROUP BY](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_groupby.htm)

Comment: Thank you I just forgot to remove some of the products